# 06 Torrent temp gauge stopped working, fans on, trouble starting sometimes

Tags: pontiac, torrent

My 2006 Torrent temp gauge stopped working, fans run all the time when car is on. sometimes it is hard to start have to pump gas pedal to get started not all the time but a lot. replaced coolant temp sensor no change. air works good. any suggestions

Comment: also Car is not overheating

Comment: Check engine light?

Comment: yes it came on.

Comment: What's the code, a coolant temp circuit code? Have you tested the wiring?

Comment: P0116 Engine coolant temperature {ETC} sensor performance. sorry took so long had to go get a scanner to see what code

Comment: You need to check what the PCM is seeing for Engine Coolant temp and Intake Air Temp. Make sure it's around ambient air temp on a cold start. There should be a smooth transition from cold to operating temp. On these cars the Instrument Cluster requests ECT sensor readings from the PCM over the serial data line. Since you're throwing a code you need to check the sensor wiring. Make sure it's not a short to ground on the signal wire.